# Linux Mint Stuck In Airplane Mode

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

As a pilot for a potential one-on-one program, my school has installed Linux on some Dells that are a couple of years old, and have placed a few of us in charge of setting up/running them.  They are running Qiana (Linux Mint v. 17) with Cinnamon 2.2. One day, the laptop began refusing to connect to wifi.  In the network settings menu, the airplane mode switch was turned to "On".  I slid it to "Off" and closed the menu.  I still couldn't connect.  Returning to the menu, I discovered, much to my chagrin, that airplane mode had turned back on.  Also, regardless of the indicated status of airplane mode, the Wireless switch only flips to "On" for a split second before reverting to "Off".  This problem has persisted through several reboots.

Getting on the internet (on a different computer of course), we discovered that this is a (relatively) common problem on similarly-configured Linux machines.  However, none of the solutions given either apply to our computer or simply don't work.  For instance, we tried running

> sudo rfkill unblock all

in terminal, which hasn't changed anything at all.  There are no hardware switches (such as Fn or buttons on the side of the laptop) to adjust.  What can we do to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you ruled out hardware failure?

Comment: @eyoung100 No, I don't believe we have.  The computer at least can detect other wireless networks, so the wireless device (not sure if it is embedded, is an adapter, etc.) couldn't have totally failed.  Point taken, though.  Still, is there a possible software solution we have overlooked?

Comment: check the fn key or the actual physical hardware wireless switch on the laptop itself.

Comment: Try mchid's advice, look on the Fn keys at all the pretty blue icons.  One of them should be a blue wireless antenna.  If its not there, check the left and right sides near the usb ports etc for a slider type switch...If it's a slider type slide the switch each direction to test.

Comment: Can you update your post with the model etc?